# python click set allowable values for option

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have created a Click command that will copy files from source to destination

The command accepts 3 parameters :

1 -  Source of files

2 -  Destination of files

3 -  Transfer mode (local,ftp)

```
import click    

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument('source')
@click.argument('destination')
@click.option('--mode', required = True)
def copy(source, destination, mode):

    print("copying files from " + source + " to " + destination + "using " + mode + " mode")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

When I call the script using this : `command.py copy "C:/" "D:/" --mode=network`

I get the following output : `copying files from C:/ to D:/using network mode`

As you can see I specified network as mode, but I want only two options : local or ftp

So how can I use Click to set the allowable values of an option ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to use [click.Choice](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/options/#choice-options)

```
@cli.command()
@click.argument('source')
@click.argument('destination')
@click.option('--mode', type=click.Choice(['local', 'ftp']), required = True)
def copy(source, destination, mode):
    print("copying files from " + source + " to " + destination + "using " + mode + " mode")
```